# SQL - How to select a computed column into another column, without recomputing it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, math

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS TotalItemsOrdered,
       'TotalItemsOrdered' AS 'Copied Value'
FROM OrderDetails;
```

The result should show up like:

---

### | TotalItemsOrdered|Copied Value  |

### | 20               |      20      |

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do have to repeat the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not identifiers.  And you cannot re-use an identifier in a `select`.  So repeat the expression:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS TotalItemsOrdered,
       SUM(Quantity) AS CopiedValue
FROM OrderDetails;
```

Only use single quotes for string and date constants -- never for identifiers.

Comment: The Computed value has a lot more calculation. So I don't want to recalculate it again . Is there a way to copy the computed value into another column without recalculating it ?

Comment: @RohithM . . . You can use a subquery or CTE.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a subquery to calcule it, then copy it.....  but.... this looks like an XY problem ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem )

```
select TotalItemsOrdered, TotalItemsOrdered as CopiedValue
from ( select sum (Quantity) as TotalItemsOrdered 
       from OrderDetails) x
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question the way I needed it :-) .